# How to determine what type of object is the sender of an event?

Tags: vb.net

Heres my sub:

```
Dim onThisTable as String ="Name"

Private Sub skill_mouseHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.MouseHover, button2.MouseHover, panel1.MouseHover, panel2.MouseHover, pbox1.MouseHover
  descriptionLabel.Text = dbClass.getDescription(sender.Text, onThisTable)
End Sub
```

Now I wish to give onThisTable a different value depending what the user pass over (panel or a pbox or a button) but I cant find what is the correct way to compare what type it is ...

```
Private Sub skill_mouseHover(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.MouseHover, button2.MouseHover, panel1.MouseHover, panel2.MouseHover, pbox1.MouseHover
  if sender is ( a button )
     onThisTable = "Admin"
  else if sender is ( a panel )
     onThisTable = "dbObject"
  else 
     onThisTable ="Name"
  end if

   descriptionLabel.Text = dbClass.getDescription(sender.Text, onThisTable)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the TypeOf keyword as descibed here ([link](http://www.a1vbcode.com/vbtip-99.asp))

```
    If TypeOf sender Is Button Then
        onThisTable = "Admin"
    ElseIf TypeOf sender Is System.Windows.Forms.Panel Then
        onThisTable = "dbObject"
    Else
        onThisTable = "Name"
    End If
```

Comment: aah,typeOf great, tx for the quick answer too